# Must I import both Pandas and Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For years I've used Pandas on a daily basis and often (but not nearly as frequently) use Numpy.  Most of the time I'll do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

But [EDIT: [prior to pandas 2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html)] there is also the option of using Numpy directly from Pandas:

```
df['value'] = pd.np.where(df['date'] > '2020-01-01', 1, 0)
```

Does anyone know if either one of these options is significantly more performant than the other?

Comment: This might be relevant [Does python optimize modules when they are imported multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296036/15497888)

Comment: `pd.np` is the numpy module, there aren't any performance differences, **it's the same exact module** (well, any time you have an extra attribute lookup there is some cost, but I suspect that isn't what you mean). But you really shouldn't use that, just for code clarity sake

Comment: @HenryEcker - yes, super relevant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pandas.np` was [removed in Pandas 2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes) and previously [deprecated in Pandas 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#deprecations):

```
<ipython-input-631-4160e33c868a>:1: FutureWarning: The pandas.np module is
 deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. 
Import numpy directly instead
```

But for what it's worth, you can check that it was the same module in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fd9ceb9dce3d62d8a9caa6ba7c127b512939452e/pandas/__init__.py#L234).

Answer (score 2):

Both are importing the same library. There should not be any performance differences. It is just an alias for the same code. However, `np.array` is preferable over `pd.np.array` because it saves you three characters to type.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I'd be concerned that it's doubling the effort then on pulling in the same library twice, but maybe that's not how it works.  Also, based on @Corralien's answer, sounds like it's kind of a moot point.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @elPastor that *isn't* how it works at all. when you `import pandas` the library itself  does an `import numpy`. If you `import numpy` again somewhere else, it simply looks for `"numpy"` in `sys.modules` and returns that, i.e. imports are always cached in python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, excellent explanation.  I'm a self-taught programmer and never learned much about the back-end nuts and bolts.  Much appreciated.